# Memorystream performance issue with multiple users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I have a section in my application that displays a PDF to a user.  I'm using memorystream to get this document.  Whenever I have more than a handful of users requests a document at the same time the performance of my application slows down.  If i have 30+ users it comes to a crawl.  Most of my users say it starts to slow as they reach the document.  Here is how I call the document

```
public FileStreamResult GetDocument(bool useDefault)
    {
        string contentType = string.Empty;
        short verificationType = VerificationType();
        MemoryStream ms = DocumentToStream(useDefault, out contentType);
        if (contentType == string.Empty) contentType = "application/pdf";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = contentType;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;" + FormFileName());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Close();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        ms.Close();
        if (verificationType == OBDocVerification.Presentation) SetVerified(verificationType);
        return new FileStreamResult(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream, contentType);
    }
```

To get the actual file it does this

```
private MemoryStream CreatePdfStream(PdfReader pdfDoc, List<MappedField> pdfFields, bool useVerifyButton, bool isLocked, bool isI9, bool isManualUpdate, string state) // 04/26/2018 DS TFS # 3161
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfDoc, stream);
            if (!isLocked)
            {
                foreach (MappedField mappedFld in pdfFields)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mappedFld.DB_Table))
                    {
                        //string v = PDFformFieldValue(mappedFld, this.docLevel);
                        string v = PDFformFieldValue(mappedFld, this.docLevel, isI9, state); // 10/04/2017 DS TFS # 2768 (added isI9)
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(v))
                        {
                            stamper.AcroFields.SetField(mappedFld.FormName, v);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            stamper.AcroFields.SetField(mappedFld.FormName, string.Empty);
                        }
                        if (useVerifyButton)
                        {
                            if (!IsPDFformFieldEditable(mappedFld) || !GlobalVariables.IsIE) stamper.AcroFields.SetFieldProperty(mappedFld.FormName, "setfflags", PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY, null);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (isI9) ValidateI9NAFields(ref stamper, pdfFields);
                if (!isManualUpdate && GlobalVariables.IsIE) stamper.FormFlattening = true; // 04/26/2018 DS TFS # 3161
            }
            //else
            //    stamper.FormFlattening = true;
            if (useVerifyButton && GlobalVariables.IsIE)
            {
                // Add "Verify" button
                string alignmentType;
                int numberOfPages = pdfDoc.NumberOfPages;
                int stampPage = GetVerifyButtonLocation(out alignmentType);
                if (stampPage <= 1) stampPage = numberOfPages;
                if (stampPage > numberOfPages) stampPage = numberOfPages;
                if (alignmentType == string.Empty) alignmentType = "bottom_right";
                Rectangle thePage = pdfDoc.GetCropBox(stampPage);
                float buttonWidth = 100;
                float buttonHeight = 40;
                Rectangle ButtonRect = CreateVerifyButtonLocation(thePage, alignmentType, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
                PushbuttonField button = new PushbuttonField(stamper.Writer, ButtonRect, "postSubmit");
                button.BackgroundColor = ButtonColor();
                button.BorderColor = GrayColor.BLACK;
                button.BorderWidth = 1f;
                button.BorderStyle = PdfBorderDictionary.STYLE_INSET;
                button.TextColor = BaseColor.WHITE;
                button.FontSize = 12f;
                button.Text = VerifyButtonTitle();
                button.Visibility = PushbuttonField.VISIBLE_BUT_DOES_NOT_PRINT;
                button.Rotation = pdfDoc.GetPageRotation(stampPage);
                PdfFormField field = button.Field;
                //field.Put(PdfName.TU, new PdfString("Save changes and return to the folder."));
                field.Action = PdfAction.CreateSubmitForm(this.submitUrl, null, PdfAction.SUBMIT_HTML_FORMAT | PdfAction.SUBMIT_INCLUDE_NO_VALUE_FIELDS);
                stamper.AddAnnotation(field, stampPage);
            }
            //else
            //    stamper.FormFlattening = true;
            stamper.Close();
            return stream;
        }
    }
```

I feel like I may be doing something inefficient here.

Comment: I bet that it is not `MemoryStream` fault but the pdf library ... anyway if `PdfStamper` (whatever it is) doesn't need `Stream.Seek/ setting Stream.Position` it should be easy to get rid of `MemoryStream` by using `HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream` directly

Comment: The only reason this code works at all is that [MemoryStream.Dispose()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs,147) doesn't actually dispose anything. In any other case you'd get an exception because `CreatePdfStream` calls `Dispose()` on the stream before returning it. In any case, MemoryStream is nothing more than an adapter over a byte[] buffer. Its performance is the same as accessing any byte array.

Comment: Any performance issues are caused by the PDF library itself or because the code essentially copies the contents of the PDF document in memory before sending them to the output stream. This *doubles* the size of RAM used. The code should write to `Response.OutputStream` directly to avoid this double buffering

Answer (score 0):

This is not a memory stream problem at all. Consider storing a generated stream and then serve it directly. If you have a large pdf file and several users than 
 your code will be executed several times with same result.